# Camera Doesn't Follow Character

Tags: game-engine, camera

So I'm working on a blender game and when I play the game it works but when I play it in camera mode it doesn't show anything. The camera is parented to the character but it doesn't work please tell me a way to fix this.

oops and please ignore the edits ive done i was keep posting the wrong .blend file

[image]

this one is the right one i promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put your camera in the same layer as your character (the hidden one), so it will be added when your character spawns.
- In the camera, add an `Always > AND > Scene (Set Camera)`, so the character camera will be set when it's added to the scene. The object field in the actuator should be kept empty to refer to self.

[image: Description]

Fixed file: [image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am already over with that problem. But if it happens again then I'll do that.

Comment: Wait... I thought that would really work but for some reason it didn't. Can you test that in my project and see why it didn't work?

Comment: Just added your file fixed in the bottom of my answer. Read the text on the blend to understand what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much! But why is there no shadows in the game? It's set to GLSL.

Comment: I have a different project and I'm having trouble again I did everything you said but I just can't figure it out can you please make a  Youtube tutorial on how to do this?